# How to maintain original array sort order with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I'm using `v-for` with Vue.js (v2.6.12) to display entries in an object e.g.

```
{
  "12345": {
    name: "foo",
    isAccepted: true,
  },
  "56789": {
    name: "bar",
    isAccepted: false,
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div v-for="item in sortMyItems(items)" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ item.isAccepted }}</span>
</div>
```

Sort method in VM:

```
methods: {
    sortMyItems: function(items) {
        var accepted = [];
        var rejected = [];
        for (var id in items) {
            var item = items[id];
            if (item.isAccepted) {
                accepted.push(item);
            } else {
                rejected.push(item);
            }
        }
        return accepted.concat(rejected);
    }            
}
```

It's important to me to maintain the object structure of `items` in the model, which is why I'm doing it this way. The problem I have is that when the `isAccepted` property of any of the items in my data structure change, Vue re-renders the items that the sort order reflects the new ordering. I understand that this is a very useful feature of Vue, but in my case I really don't want this to happen. I want the sort order to be maintained the way it is after `sortMyItems` is first called. Is there a way to tell Vue to not monitor changes or just not re-render e.g. `v-once`

Comment: at no point are you actually changing any values inside `sortMyItems`. Not sure why you're not just using `v-for` on `items`

Comment: @A.L not sure what you mean... I am using `v-for` on items, it's just that I have to sort it first by calling `sortMyItems`. Also, my item props do change. That's the problem, because when `isAccepted` changes, Vue updates the sort order which I don't want.

Comment: no, you're `v-for`ing the result of `sortMyItems`. This is basic javascript. And the answer you accepted proves this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understood your question:

You could call `sortMyItems(items)` in the `created` Lifecycle Hook and store the result in a property of `data`.

Then, you can iterate over that property in your `v-for`:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            sortedData: [];
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.sortedData = sortMyItems(items)
    }
}
```